# dnsmasq as cache

Tags: dnsmasq

I am trying to configure a DNS cache with dnsmasq.
The server responds to the query, but the response time is exactly the same as the Cloudflare DNS.
To test the DNS Server I have removed any internet DNS Server from my computer and also in the dnsmasq config file.

Here my /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
domain=raspberry.local
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
min-port=4096
cache-size=10000
```

I have tried for example:

```
dig facebook.it
```

and the Query time is circa 85 msec, end this is the exactly tile that I have if I use Clodflare DNS.
maybe there is something that I don't understand, but I think that a Query time should be less than 10 msec if I use a local cache DNS.

Here the content of the file /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
# Domain
search xxxxxxx
# CloudFlare Servers
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
search lan
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I don't try 127.0.0.1 because I use the DNS server on raspberry pi for the rest of lan. I have tried dig facebook.com and the response arrive from 192.168.100.5 that is the raspberry pi LAN IP

---

Here the content of the file /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
# Domain
search xxxxxxx
# CloudFlare Servers
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
search lan
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I don't try 127.0.0.1 because I use the DNS server on raspberry pi for the rest of lan.
I have tried dig facebook.com and the response arrive from 192.168.100.5 that is the raspberry pi LAN IP

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use your dnsmasq as caching DNS and also allow the rest of the LAN to connect to it:

Remove the upstream nameservers from your `resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
# Domain
search xxxxxxx
search lan
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

You don't need the cloudflare DNS servers here. You can add them in the configuration files that dnsmasq uses. Then, configure dnsmasq in `dnsmasq.conf` as follows:

```
domain=raspberry.local
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
min-port=4096
cache-size=10000
listen-address=<your_local_ip_address_here>
bind-interfaces
port=53
```

Now, to use the upstream nameservers you want (for example the Cloudflare one), add them to `/etc/resolv.dnsmasq`:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

Afterwards, simply restart `dnsmasq`, and you should be done:

`sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq`